# Customizable UIModalTransitionStyle Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uimodaltransitionstyle

is there a way to make a Customizable UIModalTranstitionStyle in a function easily so that the function can be customized and reused for multiple viewControllers when presenting them

Example:

```
func customTransition() -> UIModalTransitionStyle  {
        //other things here to customize transition
    }
```

its just that the standard .crossdissolve ,.fliphorizontal and all those arent what i need so i was just wondering if you could because i did it with a UIView

```
func popIn(yourView : UIView) {

        yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeDiscrete, animations: {
            yourView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(yourView)
    }
```

Comment: question, lol ill edit it (didnt mean to sound that way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to write a custom presentation transition is to write a custom presentation transition. The procedure for doing that is straightforward and well documented:

- set a `transitioningDelegate`
- implement `animationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)`
- provide an animation controller object

If you don't like that ("a bunch of NSObjects and writing super complex stuff"?) then don't try to customize the presentation transition. Conversely, if you want a custom transition animation, then do what it takes to make one.

Comment: ok thanks for the pointers, could you clarify with some code? or point me toward another question or guide with some code?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 You would actually need less code, since you probably don't need a custom presentation controller.

Comment: btw you seem kinda pissed off i was just wondering if there was an easy way to do it im willing to do the ("a bunch of NSObjects and writing super complex stuff"?) because i want a cool transition in my app it'll make a cleaner UI that is practical and awesome

Comment: thanks! you were very helpful (unlike the internet)

Comment: I... AM... the internet...

Comment: no your a person.....unless......your an A.I. pleeeeeease let me look at your code i want to see how they made you